# How to change the keyboard of the prompt input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, keyboard

I was writing code to test a math function I created.  My code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title></title>

</head>

  <p></p>

<body>

  <script>

    function Lcos(param) {

      return Math.pow(param * Math.PI, Math.cos(param));

    }

     

    var input = prompt("Enter number", "0");

    

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I've completed the code for the function I created.  I tried to print my function with the prompt code to test my function.  But the code is interrupted.  When I type the prompt code, I want the input to be typed not with the standard keyboard of my Android phone, but with the number keyboard on Android where only numbers can be entered.  Because the function I wrote is a math function, so it would be ridiculous to enter it with a typing keyboard.  You can do this in HTML.  You can specify the input keyboard by putting the type Attribute in the input tag.  But the prompt box is written with JavaScript code, not HTML code.  So in JavaScript, I need to somehow specify the input keyboard of the prompt box's input.  But I don't know how to do this in JavaScript.  Can someone explain this to me?

I know how the input keyboard is determined in HTML.  But I want to do this in JavaScript and I don't know how.  I would be very happy if someone could help me out.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. `prompt` is a very primitive feature. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a regular Javascript `prompt`.

You can, however, use an external library, like Sweetalert or Bootbox, to achieve this. Granted, this is an overkill, but depending on what you need the input for, and whether it's a part of a larger application, both of these might work for you.

## Sweetalert2

With Sweetalert2, you could do it like this.

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Please enter a number',
  html: `
    <input id="myNum" type="number" name="myNum" class="swal2-input">
  `,
  icon: 'question',
  showCancelButton: true,
  cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
  confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
  customClass: {
    container: 'wideLoad',
    popup: 'widePopup',
    actions: 'actionHolder',
    cancelButton: 'btn btn-default pull-left',
    confirmButton: 'btn btn-success pull-right'
  },
  focusConfirm: false,
  preConfirm: function() {
    const myNum = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#myNum').value;
    if(!myNum.trim() || isNaN(myNum)) {
      Swal.showValidationMessage('That is not a number!');
    }
    return myNum;
  }
}).then((result) => {
  // do something else
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

In the example above, I've made it so that the modal opens up on load. In your case, you could attach it to a button click, or to another event.

The modal contains an input with the `type="number"` attribute, and that will force the numeric keyboard to open on mobile. You can also style the prompt modal to fit the reduced viewable part of the screen once the keyboard pops up.

There's also some validation included in the modal:

- `preConfirm` activates after the user clicks on the OK button. If the condition you set is not met, the warning message triggers

The downside of this is that you rely on jQuery.

## Bootbox

Bootbox does the same thing, pretty much. But, unlike Sweetalert2, you need to include additional files - CSS and JS for Bootstrap, on which Bootbox relies.

```js
bootbox.prompt({
  title: 'Please enter a number',
  inputType: 'number',
  callback: function(result) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.5.3/bootbox.min.js" integrity="sha512-U3Q2T60uOxOgtAmm9VEtC3SKGt9ucRbvZ+U3ac/wtvNC+K21Id2dNHzRUC7Z4Rs6dzqgXKr+pCRxx5CyOsnUzg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```